# Use try catch for complete activity

Tags: android

I know it's not proper programming but I wan't to trie it anyway. I wan't a whole activity to be put in try catch.

So I tried the following: Put all code and function calls in onCreate in try catch. But still it isn't caught. How can I do this? Maybe make the whole activity class throwable or something?

edit: logcat console added

```
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@476ffb30
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:859)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:863)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:404)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:178)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-12 10:41:10.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Because I'm getting an exception and it's stacktrace isn't pointing to my code (Google map widget). Exception only happens rarely when there is no internetconnection though. (check previous topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975504/illegalargumentexception-when-showing-google-map-without-internet-connection)

Comment: Why dont you check for the connection and tell the user there is no connection instead of trying to load the Google widget which is giving you trouble?

Comment: I could do this as a last resort (Then I'd have to look up how to delete a view in an activity) but I'd like the users to view the cached map.

Comment: can you show the logcat console or the your code...

Comment: Which api are you using? The api with google maps? Emulator that is...

Answer (score 3):

create a class that implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. then in your activity's onCreate() method call:

```
// register our own exception handler to the current thread
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new YOUR_CLASS_HERE());
```

Comment: I made my problem class(which throws the unknown exception) implement UncaughtExceptionHandler. But still the exception isn't caught in  uncaughtException(Thread threadm Throwable ex) method. Are you sure this works in android?

Comment: yes, this works in android. is used it a couple of times. you have to set the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler for every Activity and for every Thread you want to monitor.

Comment: I've got it working but this actually doesn't help me since I can't ignore/catch the exception. I now can just process the throwable before it goes straight to the device.

Comment: I need to catch the exception and this didn't caught it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to prevent Force Closes and catch them instead, I recommend more effort on optimizing the code and catching portions which will throw exceptions like parsing integers, etc. To wrap the whole activity simply will not work.

Comment: I normally do this but I get an exception which doesn't point back to my code so I can't determine in which case the exception is thrown.